# "THIS" keyword conflict, when event function is nested inside the object

Tags: javascript

I have an idea to create an object `Shout`, which should take keyboard messages `onkeypress event` from the input element. When the user presses a key, there should appear alert box with shout exclamation.

The problem arises, when I want to access object properties inside the new `onkeypress function`, because keyword `this` refers to the input element itself and not to the `Shout` object.

Is there any way how to work around it?

I am not sure, if this concept is optimal, but I take it like an experiment.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>main</title>

</head>
<script>
var Shout;

function ShoutObj(_shout){
    this.shout = _shout;
    this.onkeypress = function(event){
               alert(this.shout); // shout is undefined, because "this" refers to input element
        }
}


function DoItFirst(){
    var selector = document.getElementById("s1");
    Shout = new ShoutObj("ouch");
    selector.onkeypress = Shout.onkeypress;
}

</script>

<body onload="DoItFirst()">
  <input id="s1" type="text"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't have to create an object to bind functionality . 2nd : just create a function that alerts shout --> function shout(){alert()}

Comment: @KpTheConstructor: thanks, but I have seen solution in the proposed duplicate. Here it it sufficient add: o = this;
    this.onkeypress = function(event){
               alert(o.shout); }